# Make http request from SilverLight to local host

Tags: .net, silverlight, cross-domain, web

I need to create web-page that has a button. After pressing the button I must get data from the web-server (let my web-page will be located at http://site.com/page.html) and send this data to local server (http://127.0.0.1:31258/). Local server sends response to web-page and changed data is sent to the http://site.com. This control on the page can be developed with Silverlight, but it also must be developed with html/JavaScript in the future. 
I know that browser does not allow this trick but I have to make this job done.
Can anyone show me an example of default http request (and getting response) in Silverlight and how to make cross-domain request?  Can my request be called as cross-domain or should I look for solution somewhere else?
I use Silverlight v 3.0.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is possible in Silverlight as you can put the clientaccesspolicy.xml file in your servers. Please see the links below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197955%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

[Intellisense in client access policy](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/04/06/silverlight-cross-domain-policy-file-snippet-intellisense.aspx)

Comment: Could anybody give me an example of cross-domain in JavaScript?

Comment: I dont thing you need the crossdomainpolicy.xml in case of js calls...According to my knowledge it is ensured by the client runtime systems such as Flash and Silverlight.